# How we can solve equation by putting values from given equations to any other equation?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, differential-equations, equation-solving, education

> *Action Equation*

```
ds2 = c^2*(1 - Rs/r) Dt[t]^2 - 1/(1 - Rs/r)*Dt[r]^2 - r^2*Dt[\[Phi]]^2       



schwarzschildLagrangian = 
 c^2*(1 - Rs/r[s])*(D[t[s], s])^2 - (D[r[s], s])^2/(1 - Rs/r[s]) - 
  1/2*r[s]^2*(D[\[Phi][s], s])^2
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
swEquations = 
 EulerEquations[schwarzschildLagrangian, {r[s], \[Phi][s], t[s]}, 
  s]; swEquations // TableForm
(*Specify initial conditions*)
r0 = 1 + \[CurlyEpsilon];(*Initial radial position with offset*)\
\[Theta]0 = \[Pi]/
  4;(*Initial polar angle*)\[Phi]0 = 0;(*Initial azimuthal angle*)t0 \
= 0;(*Initial time*)v0 = 0;(*Initial radial velocity*)w0 = \
1;(*Initial angular velocity*)u0 = 1;(*Initial time \
velocity*)(*Specify numerical parameters*)Rs = 1;(*Schwarzschild \
radius*)c = 1;(*Speed of light*)\[CurlyEpsilon] = 1*^-6;(*Small \
offset to avoid singularity*)maxS = 40;
sol = First@
  NDSolve[{swEquations[[1]], swEquations[[2]], swEquations[[3]], 
    r[0] == r0, \[Phi][0] == \[Phi]0, t[0] == t0, 
    r'[0] == v0, \[Phi]'[0] == w0, t'[0] == u0}, {r, \[Phi], t}, {s, 
    1, maxS}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]

pts = Table[{Evaluate[r[s0] /. sol]*Cos[Evaluate[\[Phi][s0] /. sol]], 
    Evaluate[r[s0] /. sol]*Sin[Evaluate[\[Phi][s0] /. sol]]}, {s0, 1, 
    maxS, .1}];
time = Table[Evaluate[t[s0] /. sol], {s0, 1, maxS, .1}];
frames = Table[
   Grid[{{Row[{"time = ", time[[n]]}]}, {ListLinePlot[pts[[1 ;; n]], 
       PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, ImageSize -> 300]}}, 
    Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 1}], {n, 1, Length@pts}];
Animate[frames[[n]], {n, 1, Length@pts, 1}]

Dt[r]^2/(1 - 1/r) + (1 - 1/r) Dt[t]^2 - r^2 Dt[\[Phi]]^2

angularMommentum = 
     
Map[Integrate[#, s] &, {swEquations[[2, 1]]}][[1]] == 1/Sqrt[\[Beta]]
    
energy = MapAt[Integrate[#, s] &, {swEquations[[3, 1]]}, 1][[1]] == -(
       k^2/(c^2 Sqrt[\[Beta]])
```

where k and [Beta] are appropriate constants for the following considerations.how can we canput the values from equation of energy and angular momentum to in Schwarzschild Action and simplify and again how  simplify by putting r=1/U in term of U??

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to replace in:

[image]

the functions r, phi and t by their values in sol.

First, you need to write the functions with a independent variable. I assume you want "s". Further, "Dt" needs to know the variable "s". With these changes:

```
Dt[r[s], s]^2/(1 - 1/r) + (1 - 1/r) Dt[t[s], s]^2 - 
  r^2 Dt[\[Phi][s], s]^2 /. sol
```

[image]

```
r[s]^2 Derivative[1][\[Phi]][s] == 1/Sqrt[\[Beta]] /. sol
```

[image]